# Can you spot the math bug in my tag helper method?

Tags: c#, math

I have made a tag helper to render out a star rating with 0 to 5 stars, including half stars.

This is the tag, rendering five stars:

```
<star-rating rating="10"></star-rating>
```

The value for `rating` can be any whole number from 0 to 10, which is divided in half in the helper method, to account for half stars:

```
public class StarRatingTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public double? Rating { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        output.TagMode = TagMode.StartTagAndEndTag;
        output.SuppressOutput();

        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        if (Rating != null)
        {
            double stars = (double)Rating/2;
            sb.AppendFormat($@"<span title='Rating {stars}/5'>");
            for (int s = 0; s < stars; s ++)
            {
                sb.AppendFormat("<span class='fas fa-star'></span>");
            }
            double dec = stars - Math.Truncate(stars);
            if (dec == 0.5)
            {
                sb.AppendFormat("<span class='fas fa-star-half'></span>");
            }
            sb.AppendFormat("</span>");
        }
        else
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("No rating");
        }
        output.PreContent.SetHtmlContent(sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

But my method has a math bug that I can't find. The method produces these outputs ( `()` = a star, `(` = half a star ):

```
0.5: ()(         (one too many)
1.0: ()          (correct)
1.5: ()()(       (one too many)
2.0: ()()        (correct)
2.5: ()()()(     (one too many)
3.0: ()()()      (correct)
3.5: ()()()()(   (one too many)
4.0: ()()()()    (correct)
4.5: ()()()()()( (one too many)
5.0: ()()()()()  (correct)
```

There is an obvious pattern here. What is the cause?

**Update**

I got it to work with an ugly workaround:

```
double dec = stars - Math.Truncate(stars);
if (dec == 0.5)
{
    for (int s = 1; s < stars; s++)
    {
        sb.AppendFormat("<span class='fas fa-star text-warning text-outline'></span>");
    }
    sb.AppendFormat("<span class='fas fa-star-half'></span>");
}
else
{
    for (int s = 0; s < stars; s++)
    {
        sb.AppendFormat("<span class='fas fa-star'></span>");
    }
}
```

If there is going to be a half star, it runs one for-loop, if not, it runs another, violating the DRY-principle...

Comment: `for (int s = 0; s < 0.5; s ++)` This loops once, not zero times. As you use later, `s < Math.Truncate(stars)` would work as the test.

Comment: In this case you got lucky, but in general it's never a good idea to compare a double to another value for equality (== 0.5), it's better to work in integers if you can. You could for example use an int and check if it's odd to add the half star `(rating & 1 == 1)`

Comment: `for (int s = 0; s < (int)stars; s ++)` casting to an `int` will also work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your for loop you are going up to `s < stars` this will mean for `0.5` it will create a full star, becuase it is greater than `0`. You can `Floor` the `stars` to omit the decimals. e.g. `Math.Floor(1.5) = 1` which is a possible fix, see below.

```
for (int s = 0; s < Math.Floor(stars); s++)
{
    sb.AppendFormat("<span class='fas fa-star'></span>");
}
```

EDIT:

`Math.Truncate()` would also work.

Comment: Aah.. Thanks! I may be too tired to think straight. It's 2:38 am...

Comment: Or store `Math.Truncate` result in a double var to use it as a loop bound and as a subtract variable later.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I would recommend using a `decimal` type here instead of a `double`, since you can get rounding errors when doing math (and then doing comparisons on the results) with `doubles`. You get "lucky" in your case because you're using `.5` which doesn't appear to present the issue, but, for example, consider this line of your code:

```
double dec = stars - Math.Truncate(stars);
```

If `stars` was `2.4`, then `dec` would be `0.39999999999999991`
If `stars` was `2.6`, then `dec` would be `0.60000000000000009`

Neither case would give the expected output if you then did the comparison: `if (dec == .4)` or `if (dec == .6)`. So in general, it's a good habit to use `decimal` if you're going to do math with the numbers and comparisons on the results.

---

To address the issue in your question, there are a couple of tricks you can use:

1. Cast the `decimal` to an `int` to get the whole number portion

   - `(int) 2.5M == 2`
2. Use the modulus operator (which returns the remainder of dividing one number by another) with `1` to get the decimal portion

   - `2.5M % 1 == 0.5`

For example:

```
// Loop from .5 to 10 in increments of .5 (the 'M' signifies that the number is a decimal)
for (decimal i = .5M; i <= 5; i += .5M)
{
    Console.Write($"{i:0.0}: ");

    // First write out our "whole" stars
    for (int j = 0; j < (int) i; j++)
    {
        Console.Write("()");
    }

    // Then, if needed, write out the "half" star
    if (i % 1 >= .5M) Console.Write("(");

    Console.WriteLine();
}

GetKeyFromUser("\n\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
```

**Output**

[image]